# How to get around Security Sandbox issues with Flash in an Android WebView

Tags: android, flash, webview, crossdomain.xml

I have a WebView loading a swf using loadUrl(). My app saves files from the web locally and then uses flash to show them.  Keep running into a 2148 error for the crossdomain.xml.

Anyone get around this and access files from the SD Card or application cache somewhere to show in a Flash component embedded into a WebView?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just found this on the Adobe site :(

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/860/cpsid_86018.html

Browser Integration:
Loading Local Files is not supported on Android 2.2.

I'd still like to know what's up with Android 2.3 though and the next version of Flash